# How to check multiple fields for NULL values in a lookup for exclusion script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, error, send-email

I am trying to prevent a send for records with null values in multiple fields.

I know how to apply exclusion for a single field:

```
EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "FirstName","EmailAddress",emailaddr))
```

What do I need to do in the exclusion script if I want to check multiple fields for NULL values? Like FirstName, LastName & Country. Can I add multiple fields in one script or multiple scripts for each field? any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not using exclusion scripts when you don't need to. They tend to obfuscate reporting and decisioning. Opt for using segmentation in the first instance to filter only records to send to where FirstName, LastName and Country aren't empty. If you're using Journey Builder, use a decision split and send those that don't satisfy your criteria down a branch with no messaging. IMHO, exclusion scripts have their place, but not as a substitute for segmentation. That said, you can just add multiple clauses to your evaluation in the exclusion script:

```ampscript
EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "FirstName","EmailAddress",emailaddr)) OR EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "LastName","EmailAddress",emailaddr)) OR EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "Country","EmailAddress",emailaddr))
```

```ampscript
EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "FirstName","EmailAddress",emailaddr)) AND EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "LastName","EmailAddress",emailaddr)) AND EMPTY(LOOKUP("DE", "Country","EmailAddress",emailaddr))
```

Comment: Thank you Macca